# Cannot install Paredit

Tags: paredit

I am new to emacs.
I want to install paredit mode on emacs 24. I am using Melpa.
When i do `M-x package-install RET paredit RET` or try to install it from `package-list-package` i see the error in the minibuffer:

```
Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, paredit
```

What should i do to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `M-x list-packages`. Then do `C-s` to search for paredit. If it does not appear in the list, then your package source is not configured properly and you are not getting the list you are expecting. I just checked melpa on my local and paredit is present, so your invocation should have worked.